# Export data from Perl script to .txt file

Tags: perl, export

Made this script :

```
   #!/usr/local/bin/perl

#simple export from win-services with current state v. 0.1 

use Win32::Service;

 #hash-code for service reasons
my %statcodeHash = (
     '1' => 'STOPPED',
     '4' => 'RUNNING',
     '7' => 'PAUSED'
);

my %serviceHash;


 #Going to get the data from services and export

Win32::Service::GetServices("", \%serviceHash);

foreach $key(keys %serviceHash){
     my %statusHash;
     Win32::Service::GetStatus("", $serviceHash{$key}, \%statusHash);
     if ($statusHash{"CurrentState"} =~ /[1-7]/){
          print $serviceHash{"$key"} . "THE SERVISE IS " . $statcodeHash{$statusHash{"CurrentState"}} . "\n";



     }
}
```

how can i take all the data that scrips give me, and put it in .txt file on my hard drive?

the scripts shows what services in my system and which of them is running and which not. 
i want to export this to .txt file

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of printing to STDOUT you should print it to a file for writing/appending.

```
# initialize outside foreach loop, open file for appending
open MYFILE, '>>', '/path/to/my/txtfile' or die("error writing to file $!");

# print to file
print MYFILE $serviceHash{"$key"} . "THE SERVISE IS " . $statcodeHash{$statusHash{"CurrentState"}} . "\n";
```

More documentation in perldoc

```
perldoc -f open
perldoc -f print
```

Comment: @Denis can you dump a few lines of %serviceHash?

Comment: erickb, i replaced my line with yours, it is creating the txt file, but all i see there is only this 

WMPNetworkSvcTHE SERVISE IS RUNNING

but, if you use my command, it showes you about 45 services, in cmd line, but in the .txt is only one...

Comment: how about if you change the mode to append. '>' to '>>'

Comment: a little help, whats the differnce between > and >>? didnt find in docs